# deserialize json in datatable from javascriptserializer

Tags: c#, .net, json

Hi I have to parse `json` data into `datatable` object. Bellow is my `json` data

```
{

"Figurative Expressions (Idioms)" : {

 "A" : [
         {
            "One word" : "Above all",
            "Phrase" : "chiefly, before everything else"
         },
         {
            "One word" : "Above-board",
            "Phrase" : "not open to question, honest, straight-forward, beyond reproach"
         },
         {
            "One word" : "Above-par",
            "Phrase" : "of superior quality"
         },
         {
            "One word" : "On account of ",
            "Phrase" : "for the sake of"
         },
         {
            "One word" : "On no account",
            "Phrase" : "not for any reason"
         },
         {
            "One word" : "To give a good account of oneself",
            "Phrase" : "to act with credit to oneself"
         }
      ]
   }

}
```

How do we parse this `json` data in `datatable`?

As I tried with `javascriptserializer`, it was parsed successfully but didn't get anything in `datatable`.

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
DataTable data1 = js.Deserialize<DataTable>(text);
```

Comment: What datatable? Which language are we talking about here? Show some more code -> what have you tried =)

Comment: I tried with bellow code: JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                DataTable data1 = js.Deserialize<DataTable>(text);

Comment: You can try using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). See this question and answer: [How to convert json into datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035608/using-json-net-from-string-to-datatable-in-c-sharp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert json into datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641004/how-to-convert-json-into-datatable)

Comment: I tried with Json.Net and getting this error "Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object."

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the fact that the Json in your example is not a pure array - but rather an object with one attribute called A which is the actual array.

My suggestion is to try to deserialize only text that defines A attribute (starting with square bracket) - so pure Json array. This should deserialise into a Datatable fine.